# Delaunay triangulation from voronoi tessellation

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scipy, voronoi, delaunay

I would like to know how Delaunay triangulation can be done to find the connectivity of
the cells formed by voronoi tessellation

The following is the code that I'm using to generate voronoi cells.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops

points = np.random.random((20, 2))
vor = Voronoi(points)
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

Could someone please help me with finding the cell connectivity by applying
Delaunay triangulation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vor.ridge_points` is a Nx2 array containing all the Delaunay edges. The values are the indices into the input array `points`. For example, one edge goes from point number `vor.ridge_points[0,0]` to point number `vor.ridge_points[0,1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can we add the indices of `points` to `fig`  and also draw the delaunay edges?

Comment: I'm slightly confused here. I want to draw the Delaunay edges between the points of the voronoi cell i.e `voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=True, show_points=True)` displays the points when `show_points` = 1. Now I want to cosider theses points as nodes and then draw the Delaunay edges.

Comment: I would like to generate a figure like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/59869376/8281509 .

Comment: @Natasha Have you tried drawing lines between each pair of points enumerated in this array? The two end points of the line should be `points[vor.ridge_points[i,0]]` and `points[vor.ridge_points[i,1]]`.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I mistakenly thought points were the vertices of the Voronoi cells. Now, it is clear to me. May I ask another question if that's ok? I am looking for imaging data of biological cells on which this can be applied to identify the connectivity of the cells. If there are test samples available in `DIPlib` could you please share some reference links?

Comment: @Natasha DIPlib doesn’t have any data other than three small images for various examples. But there are tons of cell data out there. For example [the Camelyon challenge](https://camelyon17.grand-challenge.org/) has 1TB of scanned whole slide images of lymph node tissue.

Comment: If there are small images of cells (a single slice from the z-stack) could you please let me know where I can find them ? I looked in the github repo but couldn't locate. Thanks a lot for your time